# Will the server raise an exception if its HTTP response can't get to the client?

Tags: http, tcp, connection, response

We have an application which creates an order and sends to the server via HTTP post.

1. Client sends the order as an HTTP request
2. Server processes it
3. Server sends the response
4. Server does some further operation on this order
5. The client receives the response and processes it.

I've been asked about what about in step3, the response won't get to the client and get lost on the way. Then the client will try to re-send the same order. And this will introduce a duplicate order problem. And how to tackle this.

I came up with the idea that the client generates a unique ID and send to the server so when the client sends it the 2nd time, the server could know that it's a duplicate order, and will only return the previous response.

But I soon remember that HTTP is built upon TCP which should have a three-way handshaking thing for the data connection. Which means:

From the client perspective,  if the client doesn't receive any response from the server, the connection will be maintained until timeout, then an exception will be thrown to let the client know.

My questions are:

1. From the server perspective, after it sends the response, how could it determine the response has reached the client?
2. There should be a three-way handshaking connection termination at the transportation layer to ensure that the connection will only be closed after the client received the messages, right? So if the message gets lost on the way, the server should trigger an exception, am I right?
3. If this is the case, the problem could simply be solved by ensure the server only does step4 if there is no exception in step3? Any other solution for this problem if my whole above idea is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is wrong. You need to look up *idempotence*. Basically every transaction needs to be idempotent, which means that applying it twice or more has no more effect than applying it once. This is generally implemented via unique transaction sequence numbers which are recorded at the server when the transaction has been completed.